# Why SetSource cannot change the value of Source?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I set the original `Source` of `MediaElement` to be `abc.mp3`, and I'm trying to play another local mp3, like `D://xxx.mp3`.

When I use `SetSource`, I found that the value of `Source` was still `abc.mp3`, but the music actually changed to be `xxx.mp3`.

Can I use `player.Source = "D://xxx.mp3";` ?

Here is my code:

```cs
//player is a MediaElement.

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await SetLocalMedia();
}

async private System.Threading.Tasks.Task SetLocalMedia()
{
    var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

    var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        Debug.WriteLine(player.Source);
        player.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        Debug.WriteLine(player.Source);//The output of these tow Debug are same
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why SetSource cannot change the value of Source?

Thank you for your time to report this, the problem is that if you call  the `SetSource`  method to set media source with local file open stream, so the `Source` property will not contain value, and it is by design.

> Can I use player.Source = "D://xxx.mp3"; ?

`Source` property is Uri type, it support http and UWP [local uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions), if the file stored in D disk, you could not set the `player.Source = "D://xxx.mp3`(file scheme). If you do want to set the source with uri value, I suggest copy the file to the app's local folder then use UWP local file uri scheme. But it will cause the app's local storage becomes larger.

```
private async void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

    var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        Debug.WriteLine(player.Source);
        player.Source = new Uri($"ms-appdata:///local/{file.Name}");
        Debug.WriteLine(player.Source);//The output of these tow Debug are same
    }

    player.Play();
}
```